# Localtableofcontents creates empty table of contents

Tags: xetex, etoc

I found that `etoc` module has `\localtableofcontents` that creates tableofcontents only in separate section. I've tried it but it makes section for table of contents which is empty. (in result I see only Table of contents header).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[left=1.9cm,right=1.9cm,top=2.7cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{Franklin Gothic Book}
\definecolor{headrulecolor}{RGB}{0,105,180}
\definecolor{headcolor}{RGB}{0,105,180}
\definecolor{sectionheadcolor}{RGB}{46,116,181}

\titleformat{\section}
{\filcenter\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{sectionheadcolor}}{}{0em}{}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}

\begin{document}

\section{Sec1}

Test

\newpage

\localtableofcontents

\chapter{First}
test % local toc
\section{First section}
test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of `\localtableofcontents`, as I understand it, is that the local contents listing is for use *within*, say, a chapter or a section, and not *before* it.

If you put `\localtableofcontents` *after* the `\chapter` command, then it works fine. If you put it before, then it is in the previous sectional division and belongs to that section.

For example,

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[left=1.9cm,right=1.9cm,top=2.7cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\definecolor{headrulecolor}{RGB}{0,105,180}
\definecolor{headcolor}{RGB}{0,105,180}
\definecolor{sectionheadcolor}{RGB}{46,116,181}
\titleformat{\section}
{\filcenter\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{sectionheadcolor}}{}{0em}{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\begin{document}
\etocsettocdepth{subsection}
\section{Sec1}
\localtableofcontents

Test

\subsection{Subsec1}

Another test



\chapter{First}
\localtableofcontents

test % local toc
\section{First section}
test
\end{document}
```

will produce two tables of contents: one for the first section listing its subsections:

[image: section toc]

and one for the first chapter listing its sections and subsections:

[image: chapter toc]

Comment: So, what can I do to create table of content in begining of my book without creating separate chapter for it?

Comment: You want a custom `\tableofcontents`, I guess. That is, you want to change the fact that `\tableofcontents` does `\chapter*` so that it instead does, say, `section*`.

Comment: You can issue `\etocarticlestyle` once, before making use of `\localtableofcontents` commands. Then they will use `\section*` and not `\chapter*`. This will also apply to `\tableofcontents` if it is used after `\etocarticlestyle`.

Comment: Also: I am not sure whether @AskingBrother meant that, but if you want to print a local table of contents at some other location than immediately after the corresponding `\chapter`, this is possible too. The `etoc` manual says to do `\invisiblelocaltableofcontents\label{foo}` after the corresponding `\chapter`, and then anywhere in the document you can do `\tableofcontents\ref{foo}` and it will print there the said local TOC.